# Remove Users group permission for folder inside ProgramData

Tags: c#

When I create a folder inside `ProgramData` folder say `Test` then I'm seeing below  permission for the folder by default for the `Users` group,

[image]

Question, can I remove all the permission for `Users` group?

I tried below code, but nothing no permission removed,

```
// This gets the "Authenticated Users" group, no matter what it's called
        SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null);

        // Create the rules
        FileSystemAccessRule fullControlRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(sid, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);

        if (Directory.Exists("C:\\ProgramData\\Test"))
        {
            // Get your file's ACL
            DirectorySecurity fsecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl("C:\\ProgramData\\Test");

            // remove the rule to the ACL
            fsecurity.RemoveAccessRuleAll(fullControlRule);

            // Set the ACL back to the file
            Directory.SetAccessControl("C:\\ProgramData\\Test", fsecurity);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, code which should work for your requirement (just tested it myself):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;
...
...

var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\ProgramData\Test");

// get the ACL of the directory
var dirSec = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

// remove inheritance, copying all entries so that they are direct ACEs
dirSec.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, true);

// do the operation on the directory
directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(dirSec);

// reread the ACL
dirSec = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

// get the well known SID for "Users"
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null);

// loop through every ACE in the ACL
foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in dirSec.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(SecurityIdentifier)))
{
    // if the current entry is one with the identity of "Users", remove it
    if (rule.IdentityReference == sid)
        dirSec.RemoveAccessRule(rule);
}

// do the operation on the directory
directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(dirSec);
```

And now to the details:

First, your idea was good to use a well-known SID and not directly the string. But the ***Users*** group is NOT ***Authenticated Users***, so we have to use `BuiltinUsersSid`

Then, we have to remove the inheritance. In your above screen shot, the entries are grayed out, so not directly changeable. We first have to migrate the inherited entries to direct ones, preserving old entries (if not, the ACL would be empty afterwards).

Then, there can be more than *one* entry for ***Users*** (in fact, there are two). We have to loop through all entries and check if it is one which has the ***Users*** sid. Then we remove it.

Some final words:

The ACL / permissioning logic is very complex, and escpecially the inheritance can lead to many problems. But it's getting better now.

I remember the first years after the introduction of inheritance (NT4 => Windows 2000), when many tools (even MS own ones) did not handle it correctly, which produced all sort of problems with invalid / damaged ACLs.

Comment: I can confirm it works, even in program files folder, even on a setup project. Nice !!!